# A function that it takes corresponding elements from the second list based on the first lists of indexes

Tags: list, haskell

I need help with this assigned problem for my programming class.

> You need to implement a function subList such that it takes corresponding elements from the second list based on the first lists of indexes.

For example, if the input is `subList [0,3,4] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, the answer should be `[1,4,5]`

```
subList :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
subList lst1 lst2
```

I am very new to programming in general so this is all i have so far...

I also need an error function if there are no similar elements in either list. e.g, input=`[0,9]` and `[1,2,3]`, the output should equal a custom error string... e.g "Input index is out of the boundaries"

Comment: `map (\index -> ...get element by index here) indexes`? To provide errors, consider `Either` as a "return" type.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Can the indices be out of order? What should `subList [4,3,0] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` be? How about `subList [0,0,0] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
Prelude> let subList lst1 lst2 = [x | (i, x) <- zip [0..] lst2, i `elem` lst1]
Prelude> subList [0,3,4] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[1,4,5]
```

Lets analize the code a bit.
We want all the values `x` present in the second list `lst2` whose indexes `i` are present in the other list `lst1`.

In the comprehension we have three main blocks:

- Before `|` is the value we will capture for each "iteration" (we want `x`, which will be the values present in `lst2`)
- The second block is were we declare from where we will be taking the values.

  - In this case we want the values and their indexex. With this `zip [0..] lst2` we are building a list of tuples where the first value of the tuples are the indexes and the second values are the values taken from `lst2` (something like `[(0, 1), (1, 2)...]`).
  - Then we take them one by one and we pattern match those tuples with `(i, x) <- ...` where `i` will be each of the indexes and `x` each of the values in those tuples explained before.
- The last block, `i elem lst1` calls the elem function from `Data.List` wich checks if a value is present in a list. This third block is expecting a boolean and as well as the other is evaluated once for each taken values from the expresion in the comprehension. In this case it will only evaluate to `True` when the value `i` (our indexes) are present in`lst1` .

Comment: Please avoid giving the solution away without a proper discussion for homework-related questions. It's likely that a beginner does not understand the code above, so the above answer only allows them to copy and submit it as the assignment solution, without learning much. The code might look so obvious that it needs no explanation, but when the OP is a beginner this might not be the case.

Comment: @chi, yeah, let me explain it a bit better!

Comment: The requested custom error message isn't present. The OP wasn't clear about what should happen if the indices aren't strictly increasing, but if they want to be able to jump around, that will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution. So as to not completely spoil your homework, the custom error portion is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
subList lst1 lst2 = map (lst2 !!) lst1
```

`map` applies a function to all elements of a list, returning the results in a new list, and `!!` gets an element from a list at a given index.

Comment: Another exercise for the reader: when the list of indices has more than one or two elements, use an `IntMap` or `HashMap` to improve efficiency.